# не сохраняет информацию в текстовый файл через FileWriter

Tags: java, eclipse, powershell

Сохраняю текст в файл через FileWriter. Если запускать программу в Еклипсе, то все сохраняет. Когда пробую запустить через Windows PowerShell - не сохраняет.
Проблема в PowerShell или в чём-то другом?

Comment: предположу, что надо увидеть полностью Вашу команду в shell и настройки окружения в Eclipse(давно не запускал Эклипс, могу ошибаться), ну и сам код было бы не плохо. Но если скинете, то хуже не будет.

Comment: Полные пути используются или относительные? Возможно у вас другой текущий каталог и вы файл не там ищете

Comment: сохраняет, но не туда, куда ты думаешь.